# Verifying hash password PBKDF2 with Java

Tags: java, hash, verification, password-encryption, pbkdf2

I am currently following a tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/java-password-hashing
Section 5.2

However, now that the has has been created, a followup question to this tutorial was.. I just hashed a password and made it unreadable - how in the world will we verify it?!

Currently i have this easy method setup:

```
public byte[] generateHash(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] salt = new byte[16];

    random.nextBytes(salt);

    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 65536, 128);
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("BPKDF2WithmacSHA1");

    byte[] hash = factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();

    return hash;

}
```

But i'm missing the actual authentication method...

Comment: You authenticate by getting the original salt that is stored with the hashed password, take the proffered password and hash it with the salt. Compare the output of this with the saved hashed password and if they match then the user is authenticated.

Comment: That's interesting, i haven't really tried it yet, but i will give it a shot soon enough. 

A question: How does this affect 'security'? 
Do we not need to 'store' a variable with both the hash and salt? Couldn't someone get a hold of the 'salt' this way?

Comment: The salt is not a secret and can be stored with the hash, or any other convenient place.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can't return value of password from hash.
You need to encode password from UI.
In the authentication method you compares saved "unreadable" password from DB(you got it now) with new password from UI making scripting of it.

Hash of identical passwords is equal.

Comment: Hash of identical password can't be equal because there is salt.